# Kubuntu Fails To Mount NTFS on startup, then succeeds but it's too late

Tags: partitioning, mount, kubuntu, ntfs, dropbox

I'm using Kubuntu 13.04 x64, I'm a complete noob at Linux and Kubuntu and have never asked a question on here before, and I have a NTFS partition on my HDD that is shared with a Windows 8.1 partition as a data drive.

When I set my path variables to my home folder directory to the partition, it works perfectly, also Dropbox is set to use the drive as well and this also works perfectly.

However, when I reboot my system, the paths reset to my Linux partition and Dropbox fails to access the partition. When the system has completely finished starting up, I can reset both the paths and Dropbox again to it without any problems.

Is there some way to make Kubuntu mount the partition at the same time as it mounts it's own partition so I don't have to do this manually everytime I boot up?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean "set the path variables"?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I meant the user paths under the user tab in System Settings where you can define your own paths for use folders.

Comment: sorry that's "user folders" not "use folders".

Comment: Do this problem appear only ntfs format ?

Answer (score 1):

You can have the partition mounted at boot time by adding a line to /etc/fstab for it.

```
sudo blkid #copy the UUID of the disk in question
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Add a new line with that UUID, and set the fs type field to ntfs and the options field to uid=1000,gid=1000.  It should look something like this:

```
UUID=xxxxxx /home/wherever ntfs uid=1000,gid=1000
```

Comment: Thanks very much @psusi I will try your answer out and let you know how it goes as soon as possible :)

Comment: Heya psusi that worked perfectly! Sorry it took a while to reply only just got back online! Thanks again for your help :)